# YUI 3 programmatically fire change event

Tags: events, onchange, yui3

I was wondering how to programmatically fire a change event with YUI3 -- I added a change listener to one select box node:

```
Y.get('#mynode').on('change', function(e) {
 Alert(“changed me”);
});
```

and somewhere else in the script want to fire that event. It works, of course, when a user changes the select box value in the browser. But I've tried many ways to fire it programmatically, none of which have worked. Including:

```
// All below give this error: T[X] is not a function (referring to what's called in .invoke(), // in the minified javascript
Y.get('#mynode').invoke('onchange');
Y.get('#mynode').invoke('change');
Y.get('#mynode').invoke('on','change');
Y.get('#mynode').invoke("on('change')");


/* Tried using .fire() which I found here: 
* http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/EventTarget.html#method_fire
* Nothing happens
*/

Y.get('#mynode').fire('change'); 

/* Looking around the APIs some more, I found node-event-simulate.js: 
 * http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/node-event-simulate.js.html, 
 * which by its name would seem to have what I want. I tried:
 * Error: simulate(): Event 'change' can't be simulated. 
 * ( (function(){var I={},B=new Date().getTim...if(B.isObject(G)){if(B.isArray(G)){E=1;\n)
 */

Y.get('#mynode').simulate('change');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

YUI 3.0 does not support simulating the `change` events, as you've discovered. However it will be supported in YUI 3.1. It is [in the trunk](http://github.com/yui/yui3/commit/1d4faea63148971515330703c6e02d3d13057408) now.

Your third attempt:

```
Y.get('#mynode').simulate('change');
```

should work in 3.1.

**edit**

It looks like you can just replace the YUI 3.0 version of `event-simulate.js` with the trunk version, and it will work in an otherwise 3.0 app. I haven't seen any issues so far.

Comment: Just a note: You must Y.use('node-event-simulate', ...) for .simulate() to be available.

Answer (score 6):

The usual solution is not to programmatically fire the event, but rather move all the event logic to a function, and instead call that function from your code where appropriate.

```
Y.get('#mynode').on('change', function(e) {
    AlertUserOfChange();
});

function AlertUserOfChange()
{
    Alert(“changed me”);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I normally do it but I really wanted to know if it was possible. I guess it isn't.

Comment: `Y.get('#mynode').on('change', AlertUserOfChange);` is all you need.  Then add the param e to AlertUserOfChange, like so `function AlertUserOfChange(e)`

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
Y.Event.simulate('#mynode', 'change');
```