# javascript event not working with IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, ie7.js

When I select any option in list then it should print its value in textbox(all html).

[image]

I tried

```
stafflist.setAttribute("onchange", "javacript:document.getElementById('id_17_enrolpassword').value = this.value;");
```

Its working in IE8+ and all modern browsers but not in IE7.

Also tried

```
stafflist.addEventListener('onchange',"javacript:document.getElementById('id_17_enrolpassword').value = this.value;",false);
```

So what changes I should do here?

Comment: The `.addEventListener()` function isn't implemented by IE until version 9, as [explained by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) (and if you read that doco page you'll see that even for browsers that do implement it you've got the syntax wrong: the second param should be a function, not a string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the javascript: label is only needed if the first script on the page is vbscript.

2) does this work better?

```
document.getElementById('stafflist').onchange=function(){
  document.getElementById('id_17_enrolpassword').value = this.value;
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

IE only fires the `onchange` event when the element loses focus - if you were to click outside the element or tab to a different element it should fire then.

You can get around this by using a different even, for example `onkeypress`

Comment: As predictable, the issue was not the code, but rather IE.  An interesing detail I'd never know, +1

Comment: _"IE only fires the onchange event when the element loses focus"_ - except that the OP says it works in IE8+. @Hugo - note that the second example in the question won't work in _any_ browser.

Answer (score 0):

do it this way -

```
stafflist.onchange = function(){
   document.getElementById('id_17_enrolpassword').value= this.value;
}
```

Comment: i tried this one as well ,but sorry to say not working (not working with any browsers)...

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't **truly** answer the question at hand, but, can't you use something like jQuery to code these sort of even handlings?

The code is a bit more readable (IMHO), and you don't have to deal this these cross-browser scripting issues yourself.

Comment: i know i can make it work easier with Jquery ,but I am editing Moodle (open source php made E-learning)...they mentioned that they don't recommend much to use jquery as they used YUI JavaScript library ,anyways i will try to include it...

Comment: Well then, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039787/onchange-in-yui